# Highcharts: how to specify file name in window.location.href exporting image to local disk

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/PDnmQ/) shows how to export a Highcharts chart to a png file, however doesn't show how to specify the file name.

Something like

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
            .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 

image.filename = "file.png";    <=== this doesn't work

// Save locally
window.location.href = image;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is the answer posted in SO


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772424/saving-images-from-html5-canvas-directly

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811897/how-to-save-a-canvas-with-image-to-a-png-file) ?

Answer (score -1):

var image = Canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                window.location.href=image; // it will save locally